# How can I fix vue router issue in a CloudFront environment?

Tags: amazon-s3, vuejs2, devops, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently working on Vue 2 app hosted on S3 and served through CloudFront. With my routing mode set to `history`, things weren't working properly upon initial deployment.

However, I was able to fix that by adding redirection rules to my CF distribution:

[image: CF Redirection Rules]

Things were working fine, but now for whatever reason, that stopped working, I'm getting a `HTTP 403` on all pages/paths I try to visit. The only difference between then and now is that my app has more pages/paths. Nothing else has changed. Here's a sample response header:

[image]

It's few and far in between, but there have been a couple of instances when I've gotten `HTTP 404`. The puzzling part is that the pages/paths load up fully, but not all the stylings get applied. For example, a fully bolded 12-sentence paragraph might display only 4 sentences as bolded.

Initially, I thought there was an issue with CF, but I have tried everything I could think of and talked with AWS Support, but nothing has come of that so far.

My next guess is that this may be a routing issue, but I'm not sure what to try. The routing issues I've faced in the past revolve around pages/paths not loading up at all so this is new territory for me, and I have not the slightest idea where to begin my troubleshooting efforts.

Has anyone faced a similar issue in the past? If so, how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, the issue originated from the way I was setting up Tailwind.

Instead of setting things up myself, I just pointed to Tailwind's CDN and the issue was resolved.

The version of Tailwind I was using was a bit old, so it could have been a dependency issue as well.